# how can I show an error image in my API does not have a image

Tags: flutter, image

Am using a API call in behind an I need to show a error image in an API; image is not founded.

This is my container for image.

I tried `onError` method but it does not have a return option.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(
            imageUrl,
          ),
          onError: (exception, stackTrace) {
            AssetImage(imgNotFound);
          },
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package. It has what you are looking for like showing error image and a placeholder image.

Example:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
    ),
  ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```